# Simple way to integrate Faye with Sinatra in a single file?

Tags: ruby, websocket, sinatra, faye

Is there a simple way to integrate Faye with Sinatra in a single file like this:

```
# myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'faye'

get '/' do 
  'Hello world!' 
end

get '/faye_form' do
  erb :form_and_message_list
end

post '/faye_form' do
  erb :form_and_message_list
  # will send messages to faye's channel here.
end

ruby myapp.rb
```

so that when I run "ruby myapp.rb" I run in a single process Faye and Sinatra servers (they will be on the same port I guess?) ?

or:  what's the closest thing to this, with the purpose of integrating Faye in Sinatra in the most "minimalistic" way ?

update: fixed example code, so that it doesn't look like I am interested in having Faye and Sinatra under the same path ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html

```
# config.ru
require 'sinatra'
require 'faye'
require File.expand_path('../app', __FILE__)

use Faye::RackAdapter, :mount => '/faye', :timeout => 25

run Sinatra::Application
```

Both Sinatra and Faye are rack apps, and you probably want them running on different paths, like with Faye at `/faye`. You could also mount faye at `/` and your Sinatra app somewhere else, although I think you'll need to create a "modular" Sinatra app to do that, and then something like:

```
run Rack::URLMap.new("/app" => MyApp.new)
```

In your example, you're sort of trying to have them both under the same path, which I don't think will work.

Comment: Oops pardon the inaccurancy of my example. What I wanted to do is exactly what you described in your code example (btw I did check Faye website right from the beginning, but when I did, I knew almost nothing about Rack, so I could not figure out that that code was perfectly fitting my use case..). 
Thanks, I will correct my example.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example of how Sinatra and Faye can work together simply.  You can view it here:  https://github.com/eterry1388/sinatra-faye-example

Your `config.ru` could look like this:

```
require 'faye'
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 9292
set :faye_client, Faye::Client.new( 'http://localhost:9292/faye' )
set :saved_data, Hash.new( [] )

get '/' do
  # This loads the saved data so if the web page is refreshed
  # or a new client connects, the data persists.
  @saved_data = settings.saved_data
  erb :index
end

post '/' do
  channel = params['channel']
  message = params['message']

  # Send data out to connected clients
  settings.faye_client.publish( channel, message )

  # Save data for future clients
  settings.saved_data[channel] += [message]

  redirect to( '/' )
end

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter 'thin'
use Faye::RackAdapter, mount: '/faye', timeout: 45, extensions: []
run Sinatra::Application
```

And your `index.erb` could look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:9292/faye/client.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var faye_client = new Faye.Client( 'http://localhost:9292/faye' );

  faye_client.subscribe( '/blue', function( data ) {
    var div = $( 'ul#blue-messages' ).append( '<li>' + data + '</li>' );
  });

  faye_client.subscribe( '/green', function( data ) {
    var div = $( 'ul#green-messages' ).append( '<li>' + data + '</li>' );
  });

  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'button#submit' ).click( function() {
      $.post('/',
      $( 'form#send-message' ).serialize(),
      function() {
        $( 'textarea#message' ).val( '' );
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<h2>Send message</h2>

<form id="send-message">
  <label for="channel">Channel</label>
  <select name="channel" id="channel" class="form-control">
    <option>/blue</option>
    <option>/green</option>
  </select>
  <label for="message">Message</label>
  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
</form>
<button id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>

<h2>Blue messages</h2>
<ul id="blue-messages">
  <%
    # The below block is only used for loading historical
    # saved data, not the Faye data!
  %>
  <% @saved_data['/blue'].each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<h2>Green messages</h2>
<ul id="green-messages">
  <%
    # The below block is only used for loading historical
    # saved data, not the Faye data!
  %>
  <% @saved_data['/green'].each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1... but I asked the question too long ago. I am not able anymore to tell which one is the best answer. I posted about this kind of common situation on meta stackoverflow, proposing that askers should be able to transfer the ownership to the question to someone who is interested in it  in order to let this kind of "forgotten" questions be administered more efficiently. But mods disagreed. So - Community - please comment and let me know whichever in your opinion is the best answer at the time you're reading and I'll try accordingly change the most voted comment to that.